# defined path from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a little problem with the syntax in Javascript. I want to work with a defined variable for a path in Javascript.

```
    function checkusername(){
        var u = _("username").value;
        if(u != ""){
              _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
              var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "http://localhost:8888/.../file.php");
              ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                          _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    }
              }
              ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
        }
    }
```

Now I want to set for

```
http://localhost:8888/.../file.php
```

a defined variable from php

```
define('Name','http://localhost:8888/.../file.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd either have to retrieve that constant via an AJAX call, or embed it into the Javascript at the time PHP is building the page.

e.g.

```
<?php
define('your_url', 'http://.....');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var url = <?php echo json_encode(your_url) ?>;

...
     var ajax = ajaxOBJ('POST', url);
```

Note that if the sole purpose of this constant is to hold a url that's passed to javascript and is otherwise never used in PHP, you might as well just use a variable - Javascript could not alter the PHP/server-side value anyways, so it's effectively a constant.

Comment: servers generally treat .js files as plain-text and have no reason to ever run them through the php interpreter...

Comment: That means the only way to make it work is to include the javascript in the .php file?

Comment: you could tell the server to treat .js files as if they were .php